# Printing a deck of cards (Python)

Tags: python, blackjack

Trying to create a deck of cards and printing them randomly. It gives me this message when I try to run my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tobi01\Downloads\blackjack (1).py", line 31, in <module>
    deal_deck()
  File "C:\Users\Tobi01\Downloads\blackjack (1).py", line 14, in deal_deck
    card = random.choice(DECK)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\random.py", line 256, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
 import random


def create_deck():
    for suit in SUITS:
        for pip in PIPS:
            card = (suit,pip)
            deck.apppend(card)




def deal_deck():
    card = random.choice(DECK)
    deck.remove(card)
    return card



CLUB = "\u2663"
HEART = "\u2665"
DIAMOND = "\u2666"
SPADE = "\u2660"

PIPS = ("A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K")
SUITS = (CLUB, SPADE, DIAMOND, HEART)

DECK = []

create_deck
deal_deck()




for i in range(13):
    for j in range(4):
        pip,suit = deal_deck
        print(suit + pip, end = " ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import random


def create_deck():
    for suit in SUITS:
        for pip in PIPS:
            card = (suit,pip)
            deck.append(card) #append not apppend




def deal_deck():
    card = random.choice(deck) #deck not DECK
    deck.remove(card)
    return card



CLUB = "\u2663"
HEART = "\u2665"
DIAMOND = "\u2666"
SPADE = "\u2660"

PIPS = ("A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K")
SUITS = (CLUB, SPADE, DIAMOND, HEART)

deck = [] #deck not DECK 

create_deck() #create_deck() not create_deck
#deal_deck() #why remove a card for no reason no...


for i in range(13):
    for j in range(4):
        pip,suit = deal_deck() #deal_deck() not deal_deck
        print(suit + pip, end = " ")
    print()
```

So many errors, give it a read,

You were mixing `DECK` and `deck` they are not interchangeable.

You were trying to call a function without calling a function. Functions needs to be called with a `()` at the end of it.

You miss spelled `append`

And you removed a card before going into the for loop calling `deal_deck()` outside of the for loop, and that's why you didn't have 52 cards going into the for loop.

There's ways to improve this code, but I just wanted you to understand your mistakes so you wouldn't make them in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Several errors here

- `create_deck` without parentheses does nothing, so you're not initializing your `deck`
- You initialize an upper case `DECK` (not the same, as python is case sensitive), so when you perform the deck shuffle you get an error because `DECK` is an empty list.

(and MooingRawr pointed out the next errors you'll get if you fix those ones :))

Comment: I had to `sum` up what you were doing sorry ;3

Comment: You also need to check that deck is not empty, since you keep removing cards from there (deck.remove(card))

Comment: actually you fixed more errors and you were quick so thumbs up (and without even using the magical function :))

Comment: @sramij I just pointed out why the OP got the first error. MooingRawr found the next errors :) Like you said, there are a lot.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. Very helpful!